# Transposing text files and adding columns

Tags: linux, pandas, awk

I have a large text file with 100000 rows and columns as like this

```
     Item   WS2.E  KE2.E  TT2.E 
     Sro01  0.2    0.5    0.55    
     Rro02  0.33   0.44   0.77
     Qro03  0.77   0.88   0.45
     Sro01  0.44   2.55   0.99
```

I just want to transpose the file as shown below and need to add one column called sample .

```
     Item   sample  value   
     Sro01  sample1  0.2                 
     Sro01  sample1  0.5
     Sro01  sample1  0.55
     Rro02  sample1  0.33  
     Rro02  sample1  0.44  
     Rro02  sample1  0.77
     Qro03  sample1  0.77   
     Qro03  sample1  0.88   
     Qro03  sample1  0.45
     Sro01  sample1  0.44  
     Sro01  sample1  2.55   
     Sro01  sample1  0.99
```

I tried with transpose function (datamash transpose) but it is not serving the purpose. Thank you

Comment: Hello user90. In SO we encourage users to make their attempts. Show us what you have tried so far, no doubt you are on the right track, you tagged awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short awk codes should help you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Item Sample value"}  
     NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,"sample1",$i}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [df.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table) and drop the variable column

```
df2=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Item'], value_vars=['WS2.E', 'KE2.E','TT2.E'])
df2['sample']='sample1'
df2.drop(columns=['variable'], inplace=True)
df2
```

If chained;

```
pd.melt(df.assign(sample='sample1'),id_vars=['Item','sample'], value_vars=['KE2.E','TT2.E','WS2.E',]).drop(columns=['variable'])
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took your snippet and saved it as `mash`.

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "Item\tSample\tvalue\n"}NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s\tSample1\t%s\n",$1,$i}}' mash
Item    Sample  value
Sro01   Sample1 0.2
Sro01   Sample1 0.5
Sro01   Sample1 0.55
Rro02   Sample1 0.33
Rro02   Sample1 0.44
Rro02   Sample1 0.77
Qro03   Sample1 0.77
Qro03   Sample1 0.88
Qro03   Sample1 0.45
Sro01   Sample1 0.44
Sro01   Sample1 2.55
Sro01   Sample1 0.99
```

How does it work?

```
NR == 1 {                                   # for the 1st line create the new header
        printf "Item\tSample\tvalue\n"
}
NR > 1 {   # for all data values 
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {             # iterate over fields greater or equal 2
        printf "%s\tSample1\t%s\n", $1, $i  # print the respective value
    }
}
```